# Testing Connection Timeout status on curl

Tags: linux, curl

I want to test whether my curl command really return "Connection Timeout" status or not. Therefore I want to try to run curl --connect-timeout 1 connect to any website that need more than 1 second to response in order for curl to timed out. But after trying to numerous website, I still couldn't get connect timeout status (because they responded so fast?). How do you suggest me to be able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's ok, I've searched through the stack overflow and find that you can use non routable IP address to simulate this.

E.g. `ping 10.255.255.1` or `ping 127.255.255.1` or `ping 192.168.255.1` all will return request timed out response.